# Finding $\lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I found a limit problem which is
$\lim_{n\to\infty}{2n \choose n}$
as we know that $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}^2={2n \choose n}$
now we could transform the given problem as $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}^2$
and as $\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}^2$ is a polynomial in $n$,
therefore, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}^2=\infty$
Please tell me if my solution is correct or not,and if it is incorrect then please provide me a solution.

Thanks

Comment: $\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni^2$ is as much a polynomial in $n$ as $\binom{2n}n$ is: it is not *a fixed* polynomial in $n$. So your argument is flawed. However, you can simply say that $$\sum_{i=0}^n\binom ni^2=1+n^2+\text{positive stuff}$$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58560

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1588733/calculate-lim-n-to-infty-binom2nn-without-using-lh%C3%B4pitals-rule

Answer (score 10):

$$\binom{2n}{n} \ge \binom{2n}{1} = 2n \to \infty$$

Answer (score 3):

$\binom{2n}{n}$ is called the central Binomial coefficient. [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient) says that the Wallis product can be written in the form of an asymptotic for the central Binomial coefficient. That is, $$\binom{2n}{n} \sim \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$$

---

This supposedly has a short proof:
$$
{2n \choose n} = 
 \frac{4^n}{\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n} x \phantom. dx < 
 \frac{4^n}{\pi} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} e^{-nx^2} dx <
 \frac{4^n}{\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-nx^2} dx =
 \frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}.
$$
In the first step, the formula for $\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^{2n} x \phantom. dx$ can be proved by using the Beta function.

The third step is clear, and the last step is the well-known Gaussian integral.
So we need only justify the the second step.

There we need the inequality $\cos x \leq e^{-x^2/2}$, that is,
$$
\log \cos x + \frac{x^2}{2} \leq 0,
$$
for $\left|x\right| < \pi/2$, with equality only at $x=0$.
This is true because $\log \cos x +\frac12 x^2$ is an even function that vanishes at $x=0$ and whose second derivative ($-\tan^2 x$) is negative for all nonzero $x \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Hope it helps.

Comment: A "short" (depending on what you call short) proof could also rely on Stirling approximation. The powers of $n$ and $e$ go away, the power of $4$ in the numerator remains, the $\sqrt 2$ factors cancel out and only one square root of $\pi n$ remains in the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively,
$$
f(n)= {2n\choose n} \implies \frac{f(n+1)}{f(n)}\ =\ \frac{2\:(n+1)\:(2n+1)}{\ (n+1)\ (n+1)}\ge2, \quad n \ge0,
$$ giving
$$
{2n\choose n} \ge 2^n.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a more elegant approach: $n^2=\displaystyle{n \choose 1}^2\le\sum_{i=0}^{n}{n \choose i}^2$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to +\infty}n^2=+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$S=\binom{2n}{n}$

$\implies S=\frac{2^n(2n-1)(2n-3)...1}{n!}$

$\implies 2^n<S<\frac{2^n(2n)(2n-2)....2}{n!}$

$\implies 2^n<S<2^{2n}$

Now using sandwich we get the limit as $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$(2n)!/(n! . n!)$ numerator contains one term of denominator and remaining factor of numerator is greater than other term in denominator. And it keeps increasing. So the whole thing tends to Infinity.